# xslt 1.0 - find unique values by several criteria

Tags: xslt, unique

I have following XML:

```
<library>
<elements>
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">A</property>
        <property name="select">true</property>
    </element>
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">B</property>
        <property name="select">false</property>
    </element>  
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">C</property>
        <property name="select">true</property>
    </element>  
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">A</property>
        <property name="select">true</property>
    </element>  
</elements>
</library>
```

I need to get output of all elements with name="books", which are selected (selected = true) and unique by author name.
Must use xslt 1.0.

Expected result:
                author: A
                author: C

Must output data only for authors A and C.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, try to write your verbal description as an XPath expression or match pattern, then follow the approach in http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 not(.=preceding::*)
```

to retrieve the unique values of the given xpath in for loop

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">           
        <ul> 
      <xsl:for-each select="//elements/element[@name = 'books' and property[@name = 'select' and .='true'] ]/property[@name = 'author' and not(.=preceding::*)]">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('author :',.)"/>
        </li>   
      </xsl:for-each>            
</ul>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT XML :

author :A author :C

Comment: You should learn about Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Just noticed that when ONLY last value is true - code is not working.              <library>
<elements>
 <element name="books">
  <property name="author">A</property>
  <property name="select">false</property>
 </element>
 <element name="books">
  <property name="author">B</property>
  <property name="select">false</property>
 </element> 
 <element name="books">
  <property name="author">C</property>
  <property name="select">false</property>
 </element> 
 <element name="books">
  <property name="author">A</property>
  <property name="select">true</property>
 </element> 
</elements>
</library>