# xslt 1.0 - find unique values by several criterias

Tags: xslt

I haved following input XML:

```
<library>
<elements>
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">A</property>
        <property name="select">false</property>
    </element>
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">B</property>
        <property name="select">false</property>
    </element>  
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">C</property>
        <property name="select">false</property>
    </element>  
    <element name="books">
        <property name="author">A</property>
        <property name="select">true</property>
    </element>  
</elements>
</library>
```

I need to get output of all elements with name="books", which are selected (selected = true) and unique by author name. Must use xslt 1.0.

**xsl solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">           
   <ul> 
     <xsl:for-each select="//elements/element[@name = 'books' and property[@name = 'select' and .='true'] ]/property[@name = 'author' and not(.=preceding::*)]">
      <li>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat('author :',.)"/>
      </li>   
     </xsl:for-each>            
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT solution dosn't work. Any suggestions?

**I have asked for help in my previous question and proposed answer didn't work in above input xml when only ONE element has select value 'true'**

[xslt 1.0 - find unique values by several criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888478/xslt-1-0-find-unique-values-by-several-criteria/35909783#35909783)

Comment: What is the expected output? What exactly do you mean by "selected and unique by author name"? As I understand that, none of the elements in your xml match these criteria: author A is not unique, and authors B and C are not selected, so I would expect an empty output, which is exactly what is delivered by your XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the technique to use here is [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml). It can seem overwhelming at first, but it is a very useful technique to use.

In your case, you want to look-up "selected" books by their author, so you would define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="book" match="element[property[@name='select'] = 'true']" use="property[@name='author']" />
```

Then, to get the distinct authors, you look at all the `element` elements, and select the ones that occur first in the key for their given author. The expression to do this is as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="elements/element[generate-id() = generate-id(key('book', property[@name='author'])[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="book" match="element[property[@name='select'] = 'true']" use="property[@name='author']" />

    <xsl:template match="library">
      <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="elements/element[generate-id() = generate-id(key('book', property[@name='author'])[1])]">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="property[@name='author']" /></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer :)